# How to use absolute import in source code when using requirements.txt, Python3?

Tags: python, pip, python-import, requirements.txt

I have a Python project with this directory structure:

```
my_project
|
|_venv/
|
|_requirements.txt
|
|_src
  |
  |_main.py
  |
  |_input_data.py
```

The file of `requirements.txt` is:

```
numpy
pydantic
```

The file of `input_data.py`

```py
class A:
    name = "a1"
```

The file of `main.py` is

```py
from src.input_data import A

print(f"{A.name}")
```

I use `pip install -r requirements.txt` first. And then I run this command

```
python src/main.py
```

I got the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".../my_project/src/main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from src.input_data import A
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'
```

It seems like the project itself is not recognised as a package. Could you please help me with the solution?

I know using a `setup.py` and the command `pip install -e .` can make it work. However, I want to try with `requirements.txt` in order to use `docker`.

I found a work-around, which is putting the `main.py` file to the root directory `my_project`. But do you have other solutions without changing the given directory structure mentioned above?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried changing the import in `src/main.py` from `from src.input_data import A` to `from input_data import A`?

Comment: Treat `input_data` as a top-level module, and ensure that `src` is on your search path when executing `main.py` (which happens automatically when `main.py` is in `src`). None of your code should be referencing `src` explicitly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem I see is that you are executing the main.py module as a script, but you need to execute it as a module.

Assuming your working directory is <my_project> folder use the following:

```
python -m src.main
```

That should enable the python interpreter to treat the src folder as a package and read the imports correctly(You could find more info about modules and packages [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html)).

Seeing your previous steps it could be helpful to create a virtual enviroment and install the src package (adding a setup.py on <my_project> folder as described [here](https://%20https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/setupscript.html)). Check virtual enviroments [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) and a useful tool [virtualenvwrapper](https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

A template for the setup.py file should look like the next code:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
setup(
    name="src",
    version='0.1',
    description='Python package',
    packages=['src'],
    install_requires=[
        'numpy',
        'pydantic'
    ]
)
```

After that you should execute the next on <my_project> folder (having your virtualenv enabled):

```
pip install -e .
```

After that you should be able to run main.py module as a script on the virtual environment, or any other script using the 'src' package modules code as a script.

Answer (score -1):

if the main.py and input_data.py  are both inside src folder, you can just import like so:

```
from input_data import A
```

You should not need to use src.input_data, that would have been needed if the input_data was in a different folder.

This error occurs usually when your python environment is active, after making changes to your project deactivate the pyenv and your local python should interpretate the code fine.

Comment: -1 for _"You should not need to use src.input_data, that would have been needed if the input_data was in a different folder."_ That makes it sound like Python imports navigate folder structures, which isn't true. Imports are resolved by searching the Python path - that's it. If `my_project` was on their Python path so that `src` was a top-level package, they would absolutely need to use `import src.input_data` from inside `my_project/src/main.py`, and `import input_data` would never be valid.